# how to print all variables values in a Makefile?

Tags: debugging, makefile, gnu-make

how to print entire Makefile's variables values out as they're read in?
it gave nothing with -d option.. So what'd be the correct one?

Comment: Have you tried reading [the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/)?

Comment: If you have time and money, I suggest this one: https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/the-gnu-make/9781457189883/ch02.html - The GNU Make Book from No Starch Press is a quite good source of Makefile related knowledge. You will find the answer there.

Comment: See the *--print-data-base* option described here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html